# share images between host and child docker

Tags: docker

I read this article http://blog.docker.io/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/ and I want to share images between my "host" docker and "child" docker. But when I run

```
sudo docker run -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker -privileged -t -i jpetazzo/dind
```

I can't connect to "child" docker from *dind* container.

```
     root@5a0cbdc2b7df:/# docker version
     Client version: 0.8.1
     Go version (client): go1.2
     Git commit (client): a1598d1
     2014/03/13 18:37:49 Can't connect to docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

How can I share my local images between host and child docker?

Comment: _is_ the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't do that! Docker assumes that it has exclusive access to `/var/lib/docker`, and if you (or another Docker instance) meddles with this directory, it could have unexpected results.

There are multiple solutions, depending on what you want to achieve.

- If you want to be able to run Docker commands from within a container, but don't need a separate daemon, then you can share the Docker control socket with this container, e.g.:

  ```
  docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
             -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
             -t -i ubuntu bash
  ```
- If you really want to run a different Docker daemon (e.g. because you're hacking on Docker and/or want to run a different version), but want to access the same images, maybe you could run a private registry in a container, and use that registry to easily share images between Docker-in-the-Host and Docker-in-the-Container.

Don't hesitate to give more details about your use-case so we can tell you the most appropriate solution!

Comment: +1 for for the solution of making the socket and bin directory a volume. I use that solution myself to run a Jenkins-slave as a Docker container while still being able to build the images on the host.

Comment: Thank you! I think solution with socket sharing will be pretty good. About my use-case: i have a lot of services, each running in separate container. But there are some situations when some service depends on specific version of another, and i can't sheep only latest versions. So i want to have a another container that will run all other containers inside it. And i will ship only one this container. But I want to share images because I don't want to re download it each time when my "parent" container just increase version of some service.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why you want to run a group of containers within another containers... If you have the time to explain, I'll be happy to read about it!

Comment: @jpetazzo: we are interested in running a group of containers within containers to simulate datacenters. In essence we want to be able to simulate machine and network link failure to test the behaviour on our database (C*) and our Akka application. Sharing the docker daemon of the host through the socket would cause all the newly created containers to run at the same level. Stopping a whole DC at once would be hard as opposed to just stopping a single container representing the datacenter. We now use a private repository but preventing a pull on every DC container would increase performance.

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen: unfortunately, the current graph drivers don't like to share the content of `/var/lib/docker` with other things. However, you might be able to do something funky like using one driver in the "outer" Docker, and another in the "inner" Docker. I would probably try BTRFS in the "outer" docker and AUFS in the "inner" Docker. Then you can make a template "DC container", with images pre-pulled; then just start multiple copies of it.